# onmouseout event fires wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function where onmouseenter and onmouseout work in conjunction with each other, however, if the user moves back and forth moving in and out, sometimes the function can't catch up and the end result is backwards. Is there a way to have mouseout stop the function and the last onmouseenter be the function that is ran?

```
<div class="id">Test</div>
<div class="id">Test</div>
<div class="id">Test</div>

$('.id').on('mouseenter', function(){
     $('.id').addClass('bordered').removeClass('nonbordered');
}).on('mouseout', function(){
     $('.id').removeClass('bordered').addClass('nonbordered');
});
```

Comment: mouseleave would be better than mouseout

Comment: *"Is there a way to have on mouseout stop the function and on the last onmouseenter be the function that is ran?*" this last sentence is confusing. Can you clarify?

Comment: You mean like jQuery's [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) function?

Comment: Can you do it without JavaScript? That would depend on the HTML markup.

Comment: using just basic HTML as in the example, when the user does mouseenter last, I need it to run the mouseenter function instead of the mouseout function

Comment: if the user moves in and out real fast, sometimes the mouseenter doesn't fire

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML and CSS so that your question shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself? For example, is `#main` **inside** `#id`? That makes a huge difference to the solution. I can't seem to [**replicate your problem**](https://jsfiddle.net/514w31yw/).

Comment: It seems to works very fine. Check [this out](https://jsfiddle.net/mh83xhzy/). If you have ommited any code, please add it.

Comment: maybe its just a server thing going back and forth then